# JavaScript dollar function, function $() error

Tags: javascript, function

I've come across the dollar sign function over the internets and decided to use it for a javascript toggle menu. However, the "$" symbol makes my code fail.

This is what I'm trying to use:

```
function $() {
        var elements = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            var element = arguments[i];
            if (typeof element == 'string')
                element = document.getElementById(element);
            if (arguments.length == 1)
                return element;
            elements.push(element);
        }
        return elements;
    }

    function toggle(obj) {
        var el = $(obj);
        el.style.display = (el.style.display != 'none' ? 'none' : '' );
    }
```

The $ from "function $(){" seems to break the code. How do you declare this function?
If I replace $ with "anything", it works, but not as a dollar function...

Comment: do you also use jquery or some other javascript framework ?

Comment: Can you explain why you feel `'$'` is a good name for this function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The dollar sign is not a standard Javascript function, but is part of a third party library.

There are two well-known libraries which use the dollar sign in this way.

The older one is called [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/), but the one which is currently in vogue, and most likely to be the one you've seen in use is [JQuery](http://jquery.com/).

Both these libraries would be used by adding a `<script>` tag to your HTML page, to include the library code, after which you can use their functionality.

Most of the functionality of both these libraries is contained within their respective `$()` functions. In the case of JQuery, you can also refer to the `$()` function as `jQuery()` to prevent namespace clashes, in the event that you wanted to use both of them.

I suggest reading up on JQuery before continuing -- JQuery is very powerful, and adds a lot of functionality, but the coding style for writing JQuery code can be quite different from regular Javascript, and can take a bit of getting used to. And that's quite apart from learning the API and finding out what it can do.

To actually answer your question -- which is how to declare `$` as a function name, I suggest having a look at the JQuery source code to see how they do it. However, I managed to produce a working `$()` function first time I tried, like this:

```
var $ = function() {alert('dollar works for me');}
$();
```

But to be honest, I wouldn't do that. If you really want to use the `$()` function in the way it's being used in other sites, you need to use JQuery. It does a whole lot more than just wrapping `document.getElementById()`.

By the way, JQuery and Prototype are not the only similar libraries out there. If you're interested in this sort of thing, you may also want to look into [MooTools](http://mootools.net/), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), and a few others.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

The $ sign is a notation for various javascript frameworks (prototype/jQuery).  Since replacing it with "anything else" works, you most likely have a clash between that inline function and the framework you are using.

In itself, the notation and function is correct, as the following example shows.

Open a new tab/window and enter this on the address bar:

```
javascript:eval("function $() { alert('hi'); } $();");
```